# Router navigate doesn't seem to be changing component

Tags: angular

I've currently got a router with (only relevant) 2 routes:

```
{ path: ':org', component: OrgComponent, resolve: [ OrgResolver ] }
{ path: '', component: NotFoundComponent },
```

The resolver is pretty straight forward:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private orgService: OrgService) { }

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Org> {
    return this.orgService.getOrgData(route.params['org']).map(function (org) {
        if (org === null) {
            this.router.navigate['/'];
            return null;
        } else {
            return org;
        }
    });
}
```

If I directly go to `/`, I hit the NotFoundComponent. If I go to a route like `/invalid`, which OrgService returns as null, thus invalid, the app does route to `/`, but the component stays the same. And because there's no `:org` in the path, the API call fails (I check to make sure you pass in a string of some sort), and the app crashes with this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
```

I can fix the crash part, but what I'm expecting is that if you go to an invalid location, I want to forward you on to somewhere else. In the long run, this will be a 404 location, but right now, I'm just trying to get a hang of the router.

Am I not understanding something about how navigate is supposed to work?

Comment: For routes with path `''` and no children use `pathMatch: 'full'`

Comment: You seem to be failing to call `navigate` method correctly: `this.router.navigate(['/']);`, not `this.router.navigate['/'];`

Comment: @VohidjonKarimjonov Sorry, that mistake came in while I wrote a bunch of tests to figure out what was going on. My original code definitely had it as a function, not array.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Adding `pathMatch: 'full'` didn't help :(

Comment: That's possible, I think you should still use it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I will; I forgot about it existed. The router is still throwing me for a loop. If you have any other thoughts on how to fix the error, I'd appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

A coworker pointed out to me I was using a standard function in `.map`, not an arrow function. Because of that. `this.router.navigate` was the part that was failing, not the actual loading of components.

Changing

```
return this.orgService.getOrgData(route.params['org']).map(function (org) {
```

to

```
return this.orgService.getOrgData(route.params['org']).map((org) => {
```

Solved the problem.